# Black Screen when booting live usb (Ubuntu 12.10 and 13.04)

Tags: boot, live-usb, windows-8, uefi

this forum is my last chance. I have a Acer Aspire X3470 and I am trying to boot ubuntu live USB. I already tried to boot from the Ubuntu desktop image 12.10 and 13.04 but with the same result. When I boot my pc I see the grub menu and I select the first entry for booting without installation. After that I see that my USB device tries to read some data (I see it on the led) and then it stops reading from the device. Afterwards nothing happens and all I see is a black screen.

I already tried the following boot parameters with no result:

- delete the quiet and splash entries
- nomodeset
- xforcevesa
- vga=normal
- radeon.modeset=0, radeon.modeset=1, i915.broken=0, i915.broken=1
- acpi_osi=Linux, acpi=off
- acpi_backlight=vendor

My PC has the following properties:

- Windows 8 pre installed
- GPT
- Acer Bios (newest firmeware)
- Secure Boot, Legacy boot

I already tried all kind of combinations for secure boot and legacy boot and I disabled the fast boot option. After selecting the grub menu entry the menu disappears and everything I can see is my black screen (but the screen device is on just as the backlight) nothing more. I tried to force grub to be more verbose and to show me what he is doing but with no success. I have no hint what happens in background and why ubuntu is not loading.

I copied the ubuntu desktop images with win32 disk imager, unetbootin and usb live creater always with the same result :-(

Thanks in advance

@Solved: Hello I solved the problem. The usb stick was formated with fat and should be formated with fat32.

Comment: Have you looked at this post: http://askubuntu.com/questions/162075/my-computer-boots-to-a-black-screen-what-options-do-i-have-to-fix-it?

Comment: @Lucio The OP has already tried most of the options given in that question.